# Cannot read property 'image' of undefined angular 6

Tags: angular, typescript, undefined

When trying to get the details it renders to the dom but it gives an undefined error.
here is an image to show

[image]

This is Book Details Component

```
export class BookDetailsComponent implements OnInit {
  book: Book;
  books: Book[];
  id: string;

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private booksService: BooksService, private http: Http) { }

  async getAsyncData() {
    this.books = await this.http.get('/assets/books.json').toPromise().then(
      data => this.books = data.json().books
    );
    this.book = this.books.filter(book => book.id === this.id)[0];
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.route.params.subscribe(
      (params: Params) => {
        this.id = params['id'];
        if (this.book) {
          this.book = this.booksService.getBook(this.id);
        } else {
          this.getAsyncData();
        }
      }
    );
  }

}
```

And this is the getBook function from service

```
getBook(id: string) {
    return this.books.filter(book => book.id === id)[0];
  }
```

Comment: can you also share the html code

Comment: You have no reference to an `image` property in your code.

Comment: You know it was working fine but when refresh the data is gone, Do you know how to solve this??

From your comments. Solution you have to once you get value then you have to set some common service or some other way like local storage and you can get. Because you are capture the data via routerparams.

Answer (score 11):

The issue with this is normally that you use a line such as

```
<img src="{{ book.image }}" />
```

in your code. When the component is first rendered, your book object is still undefined (see `book: Book;`: no value definition here).

One solution is to wrap references to book in an `*ngIf`ed block:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="book">
    <img src="{{ book.image }}" />
</ng-container>
```

Or, alternatively, if it's just this single image, do

```
<img src="{{ book.image }}" *ngIf="book" />
```

Or alternatively, if you don't mind the img being in your DOM with an empty src:

```
<img src="{{ book?.image }}" />
```

Comment: it just not the image it gives to the whole book details like it is not there.

Comment: You know it was working fine but when refresh the data is gone, Do you know how to solve this??

Comment: why are u using [0]?

Answer (score 0):

When u refresh the page it initially calls the ngOninit method.

here initially if the condition becomes false and it chooses else...

here it calls getAsyncData()...

this.book = this.books.filter(book => book.id === this.id)[0];

in this filter `book.id` is empty so it throws an undefined error.